# ValuError using import function in class

Tags: python, function, class, import, nameerror

I'm sure there's a simple explanation for this (beyond just that I'm new to Python), but let's say I have two file in the same directory. One is this little script in a file named `lexicon.py` that checks user input:

```
def string_checker3(action):
    try:
        check = isinstance(action, basestring) 
        if check:
            return True
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print "We need a string here!"
        return None

def Chipcar_testgreeting(action):
    action_split = action.split()
    for i in action_split:
        strcheck = string_checker3(action)
        if strcheck == None:
            StartGame
        else:
            pass
```

The other script, my main script, is called `newGame.py` and has a class like this, within which I would like to call the `Chipcar_testgreeting(action)` function.

```
from lexicon import *

class ChipCar(Scene):



    def enter(self):
        print "What's up mothafucka! Get in the Bran Muffin car!"

        action = raw_input(">  ")
        user_test = lexicon.Chipcar_testgreeting(action)
        user_test

        if(action == "shut up chip" or action == "oh no, it's chip"):
            print "forget you!"
            print action
            return next_scene('Your_death')
            #return 'Death' 
        elif(action == "hi chip" or action == "hello chip"):
            print "What's up?!?! Let's go to O&A..."
            return next_scene('Chip_in_studio')
        else:
            print "what's wrong with ya are ya stupid or sumptin? Let's go to my mudda's house, I think Lamar's there..."
            return next_scene('Chip_mom_house')

FirstScene = ChipCar()
StartGame = FirstScene.enter()
```

However, I get this error now:

```
user_test = lexicon.Chipcar_testgreeting(action)
NameError: global name 'lexicon' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't import `lexicon`.  I think you have the idea imports backwards.  If you want to use `lexicon` in `newGame`, you need to import `lexicon` in `newGame`, not the other way around.  Your code also has various other errors, so you should probably read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial).

Comment: @BrenBarn just left the import out of the post, fixed now. Definitely running the script with the correct import and getting error as posted.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote `from lexicon import *`, all the importable names from that module are available to you directly (in other words, you don't need `lexicon.` anymore).

If you write `import lexicon`, now you have only imported the `lexicon` name into your module, and you need to use it and the scope-resolution operator (that's the `.`) to get to the other names of objects inside that module. In this case, you can use `lexicon.Chipcar_testgreeting(action)`.

So, either replace `from lexicon import *` with `import lexicon`, or change `lexicon.Chipcar_testgreeting(action)` to `Chipchar_testgreeting(action)`.

**The recommended option is to use `import lexicon`**.

---

Once you sort that out, you need to resolve another major issue which is this:

```
if strcheck == None:
    StartGame
else:
    pass
```

Not sure what do you expect `StartGame` to do here, since there is nothing with this name in the `lexicon.py` module.